# 動的配列によるヒープの実現

Tags: c

ヒープを作成しようとしています
要素xを挿入するinsert()を完成させたいのですが
何を書き加えればよいでしょうか

```
include <stdio.h>            //printf,ramd用
include <stdlib.h>           
include <string.h>      
include <time.h>            
define INIARRYSIZE 1  
int* pA;                     
int sA;             
int size;           

void create()
{
    sA = INIARRYSIZE;   //配列の現在サイズを初期化
    if((pA = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*sA))==0) exit(1);
    size=0;             //記憶中のデータ個数を初期化
}

void insert(int x)
{
    if(size==sA-1)
    {
        int* oldpA = pA;
        sA = sA*2;
        if((pA=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*sA))==0) exit(1);
        memcpy(pA, oldpA, sizeof(int)*(size+1));
        free(oldpA);
    }
    size++;
    pA[size]=x;
    printf("%d",size);
}
```

Comment: `realloc` を使う、というのではダメでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/198037